# Making a div scroll causes it to jitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

The problem that I'm trying to resolve can be seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AAyLj/14/

Basically, when I scroll the papa div, the boy div is supposed to move up/down.  This is working fine but there is a bit of a jitter on the boy div.  This is because (I think) the js isn't being processed fast enough.  On a powerful Mac, this doesn't happen - but it happens on PC's.

Is there a way to overcome this jitter with js or css?  Thanks.

UPDATE:

I cannot use fixed position because there are other elements on the page (not shown in the jsfiddle) that will skew the look if I keep the boy div as position:fixed.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this using jQuery?

Comment: If you have got your answer and it works, accept the right anser from below by clicking on the check on the left on the answer so it turns green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As karthikr is saying, you should probably use the CSS `position: fixed`. If that is not what you want, you could use the `animate` function. It gives a nice small delay to it.

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AAyLj/25/) to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks all.  I should have stated in my question that I can't use position fixed.  There are a few reasons for that: 1) the boy div has to be contained inside the papa div 2) there are other divs (not shown in my jsfiddle) that expand and contract and which will end up ruining the look if i position the boy div as fixed.

Comment: Actually this answer seems to work.  Thanks everyone and Rune! See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/AAyLj/29/

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with this css, no js necessary. http://jsfiddle.net/AAyLj/27/

```
.papa {
    min-height: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;    
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top:10px;
}
.boy {
    height: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 200px;    
    width: 70%;
    float:left;
}

.girl {
    height: 800px;
    min-height: 800px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
}
​
```